# How to access class object inside the class in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I've got flask running in a class

```
from flask import Flask

class Server:
    app = Flask(__name__)

    def __init__(self, object_with_data):
        self.object = object_with_data

    @app.route("/")
    def hello(self):
        return self.object.get_data()

    def run():
        self.app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

but I get an error saying

`TypeError: hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

How do I get access to an instance of the object when running flask within a class?

One dirty solution I thought of was using sockets to create a link between my server class and the object_with_data class, but I'm sure someone will know a better way to do this.

I read something about event handlers, but I don't fully understand that.

Comment: You cannot do this and you should not try. It does not make sense to wrap your `app` instance and the handlers within a class. What, exactly, are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @DanielRoseman In my actual code it says 'class Server(Thread):' so I can start the server in a thread. And this way the server logic is separate from the application logic.

Comment: You should ideally use an external uWSGI wrapper to expose your app on its own thread/process

Comment: Well that makes even less sense. What is managing these threads? You shouldn't be doing that, you should be getting your WSGI server to do it.